# Different database for GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine

How to use another database for Google App engine than the datastore. And if it could be possible to access it with php(quercus).

Comment: If you want to use PHP and you don't want to use the datastore, App Engine is probably not for you.

Comment: Question is related to a really old version of App Engine. It has drastically changed since then. Even the answer isn't right anymore. You can use App Engine with Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in practical terms. Datastore is the only supported database at the moment.

You *could* have a database on another server and access it via RPC (REST, WebService), but this would not be an integrated approach and would add more work to the project. For example you could set up a MySql server somewhere and use [phprestsql](http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/) to setup a REST interface and then acces it from GAE.

Answer (score 1):

@Peter Knego

i am also looking for same. I want to host my java web application on GAE and databse on different Server(Godaddy).
Google data store is free for only 6 months, So i would like to use database of different hosting(goDaddy). So is it possibe??

I am able to use database of my hosting(goDaddy) from my local system but when i upload my application to GAE that it doesn't work. I know it is possible in case of other servers but what about GAE.